# Python Plotly - graph issue with comparing difference between 2 bar graph values each day - error ONLY when filtering out weekends

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, graph, plotly

I have two scores each day in a bar graph and I am denoting the difference between the score for each day. It works fine as is, but I want to exclude weekends.  When I do this, I'm getting an error.  I'm unsure what I am doing wrong, but any help is appreciated.  I've also provided an image of the desired output - see:   [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7T5QU.png

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import math
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
   'score': [11,42,31,22],
   'dates': ['7/1/2022','7/2/2022','7/3/2022','7/4/2022'],
   'weekend': [0,1,1,0],
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
   'score': [44,45,26,22],
   'dates': ['7/1/2022','7/2/2022','7/3/2022','7/4/2022'],
   'weekend': [0,1,1,0],
})

#df1 = df1[(df1['weekend'] == 0)] When I filter out weekends this doesn't work, otherwise it's fine
#df2 = df2[(df2['weekend'] == 0)]

y1 = df1['score']
y2 = df2['score']

c = []
i = 0

while i < len(y1):
    i = i
    q = y1[i]-y2[i] 
    c.append(str(q))
    i=i+1

fig = go.Figure(data=[
    go.Bar(name='SF Zoo', x=df1['dates'], y=y1),
    go.Bar(name='LA Zoo', x=df2['dates'], y=y2, text=c, textposition='outside')
])


fig.update_layout(barmode='group')
fig.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few options to return the subset of values in `y1` and `y2` in an array-like format after filtering out weekends. Update your code with either of these options:

**Option 1:**

```
y1 = df1['score'].values
y2 = df2['score'].values
```

**Option 2:**

```
y1 = df1['score'].to_numpy()
y2 = df2['score'].to_numpy()
```

**Option 3:**

```
y1 = df1['score'].tolist()
y2 = df2['score'].tolist()
```

Comment: Geez, I don't even know how didn't even think of this.  I am so grateful, thank you!